# Regular expression for single quotes

Tags: php, regex

After a long time of trying to find a good regular expression to find, and then replace, single quotes (‘’) with single guillemets (›‹), taking care of apostrophes, I came up with this:

`‘((([^‘]*’)*[^‘]*)+)’`

I've successfully tested it at PHP Live Regex. However, it only works with preg_match and only sometimes with preg_replace (as replacement, I use `›$1‹`).

Could it be a problem with backreferences? Does anyone know a better solution?

**EDIT**:

The issue I get is *catastrophic backtracking* when I am trying to change strings similar to

```
one ‘two’s’ ‘three’ four
```

to

```
one ›two’s‹ ›three‹ four
```

Comment: Could you supply any example string? Also, what is the issue you get?

Comment: Also, suspected results would be useful.

Comment: Feel free to modify [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/oT9oJ0/2) to show the problem you are having.

Comment: Yup, it says catastrophic backtracking! :-( Thanks for the reference, @stribizhev, will consult the site more often.
@Num6 the expected result is really quite simple: change `one ‘two’s’ ‘three’ four` to `one ›two’s‹ ›three‹ four`

Comment: Does [`‘((?:[^‘]*’)*[^‘]*)’`](https://regex101.com/r/oT9oJ0/4) fix it for all your input strings? The one you supplied does not actually cause catastrophic backtracking, but it is clear the issue is with the nested quantifiers and optional patterns inside the group.

Comment: @stribizhev indeed it does! Perfect! I've tried it with real text and it said catastrophic backtracking, but now it works. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
‘((?:[^‘]*’)*[^‘]*)’
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oT9oJ0/4)

The main change is removing outer `(...)+`, and that created nested quanitifier issue. Both `[^‘]*’)*` and `[^‘]*` can match emtpy strings, and when enclosed into group with `+` quantifier, the number of steps to complete the match grew exponentially.